# How do I solve this GPG Key error

Tags: apt, updates, pgp

This occurs every time I run `sudo apt update` :

[image: This occurs every time i run update]

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to install the GPG keys for Microsoft Edge.

```
sudo wget -O- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-edge.gpg
```

For a detailed MS Edge guideline, you can follow this:
https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-microsoft-edge-browser-on-ubuntu-20-04/